# Solve complexity of recurrence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, asymptotics

I'm currently trying to solve this recurrence relation using substitution.

$T(n) = c_1$ for $n = 1$

$nT(n-1) + c_2$ for $n > 1$

As of right now, I have $T(n) = nT(n-1) + c_2$, $T(n-1) = nT(n-2) + c_2$, $T(n-2) = nT(n-3) + c_2$.

Substituting these values into the original equation:

$$
T(n) = n(n(nT(n-3) + c_2) + c_2) + c_2
$$

From there I used $k = n - 1$, where $T(n) = (n^k) T(n - k) + (n^{k-1}) +\ldots+ (n^0) * c_2$.

Finally replacing $k$'s value with $n - 1$ gave me $T(n) = (n^(n-1)) * c_0 + (n^{n-2}) * c_2 + ... + (n^0) * c_2$. I'm not exactly sure what to do after this point as it looks like some summation formula is needed.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! Please format your equations using mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: $T(n-1)= \color{red}{(n-1)} T(n-2) +c_2$ ?